# Is there any way to retrieve the executed query from java ResultSet?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I created a method called `public static ResultSet ExecuteSQLQuery(String myQuery)` now at run-time I need to retrieve the executed query from the ResultSet.

I wonder if it is possible to retrieve the executed query from the ResultSet ?

Comment: But... you are passing the query to method. What's the problem?

Comment: let say i m using a query generator so i don't know the query content.
on my application two steps: a query is used to fill some data then come a dynamic search tool that have visibility only on the ResultSet.

Comment: So fix that. This is just a minor design problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: **No**.

It might be possible to use `getStatement` from the ResultSet. Some JDBC drivers may expose the query in the statement's `toString` method, but even if this is the case it should not be relied upon.

You'll have to save the query and keep it around if you want to use it later.

You could create a new type of ResultSet that includes the query and return that:

```
public class ResultSetWithQuery extends ResultSet {
    private String query
    ...
}

public static ResultSetWithQuery ExecuteSQLQuery(String myQuery);
```

Comment: thank you Adam, I have in some cases multiple resultSets at run-time, is using  {public static HashTable<ResultSet,String> myQueries } a wise decision as a store for my queries and a way to identify them ?

Comment: That might work. You'd have to make sure that ResultSet implements hasCode and equals properly. Or you could return the query with the results in a custom object. I edited the answer to show that.